# Calculating nth fibonacci number using the formulae in python

Tags: python, algorithm, fibonacci

I am calculating the n-th fibonacci number using
(a) a linear approach, and
(b) [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) expression

Python code:

```
'Different implementations for computing the n-th fibonacci number'

def lfib(n):
    'Find the n-th fibonacci number iteratively'
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a

def efib(n):
    'Compute the n-th fibonacci number using the formulae'
    from math import sqrt, floor
    x = (1 + sqrt(5))/2
    return long(floor((x**n)/sqrt(5) + 0.5))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  for i in range(60,80):
    if lfib(i) != efib(i):
      print i, "lfib:", lfib(i)
      print "   efib:", efib(i)
```

For n > 71 I see that the two functions return different values.

Is this due to floating point arithmetic involved in efib()? 
If so, is it then advisable to calculate the number using the [matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form)?

Answer (score 10):

You are indeed seeing rounding errors.

The matrix form is the more accurate *and* much faster algorithm. [Literateprograms.org](http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_%28Python%29) lists a good implementation, but it also lists the following algorithm based on Lucas numbers:

```
def powLF(n):
    if n == 1:     return (1, 1)
    L, F = powLF(n//2)
    L, F = (L**2 + 5*F**2) >> 1, L*F
    if n & 1:
        return ((L + 5*F)>>1, (L + F) >>1)
    else:
        return (L, F)

def fib(n):
    if n & 1:
        return powLF(n)[1]
    else:
        L, F = powLF(n // 2)
        return L * F
```

Take a look at [Lecture 3 of the MIT Open Courseware course on algorithms](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-3-divide-and-conquer-strassen-fibonacci-polynomial-multiplication/) for a good analysis of the matrix approach.

Both the above algorithm and the matrix approach has Θ(lg n) complexity, just like the naive recursive squaring method you used, yet without the rounding problems. The Lucas numbers approach has the lowest constant cost, making it the faster algorithm (about twice as fast as the matrix approach):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('fib(1000)', 'from __main__ import fibM as fib', number=10000)
0.40711593627929688
>>> timeit.timeit('fib(1000)', 'from __main__ import fibL as fib', number=10000)
0.20211100578308105
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is this due to floating point arithmetic involved in efib()?

Yes, it is.  Within `efib` you have

```
>>> log(x**72)/log(2)
49.98541778140445
```

and [Python floats have about 53 bits of precision](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) on x86-64 hardware, so you're running close to the edge.

Answer (score -1):

I have a very simple purely python code...

```
def fibonum(n):   # Give the nth fibonacci number
    x=[0,1]
    for i in range(2,n):
        x.append(x[i-2]+x[i-1])
    print(x[n-1])
```

Comment: There's no need to build up a list in memory with `.append`. You can just use two variables -- see the definition of `lfib` from OP.