# how to get rid of lots of function calls?

Tags: python, recursion, decorator

how to get rid of lots of function calls? Here is an example of the recursive function:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
      return 1
    else:
      return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

I heard you can do it with decorators easily but I don't know how to use them

Comment: Why are you trying to accomplish this? You can't really avoid function calls if you're writing a recursive function.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12103893/100297

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have looked over your algorithm already carefully and eliminated any redundant calls, you could try to rewrite your function in an *iterative* way (ie using loops rather than recursion).

Recursion can often express a solution to a problem in a nice way, but it is rather memory hungry (saving state on the stack repeatedly) and not that speedy due to all the function calls. I see its main benefit in its expressive power.

[Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is another option, so rather than re-computing (calling a function over), you first look up to see if you've previously computed (and stored) a value already and use it instead.

Comment: I agree that here it's better to use a loop instead of a recursion. But  sometimes you want your code to look short and nice. Also it's quicklier to write a recursion instead of a loop.

Comment: Levon: Recursion has it's place; a good divide-and-conquer algorithm is best coded as a recursion.

Comment: @emilchess "quicker to write" doesn't always translate to "faster to execute" though :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not against recursion, but just looking at the trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail-recursive_function) optimization, which is basically a technique to convert recursive programs to iterative without rewriting them. For example, if you call your factorial function with n = 1000, Python fails complaining that "maximum recursion depth exceeded". However, when you rewrite the function to be tail-recursive:

```
def tail_factorial(n, result=1):
    if n <= 1:
        return result
    else:
        return fac(n - 1, result * n)
```

and then use a "trampoline" to call it:

```
def trampoline_factorial(n):

    def fac(n, result=1):
        if n <= 1:
            return result
        else:
            return lambda: fac(n - 1, result * n)

    f = fac(n)
    while callable(f):
        f = f()
    return f
```

you can evaluate 1000! without any problems.

Tail-call optimization can be indeed automated in Python using decorators, see e.g. [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496691-new-tail-recursion-decorator/)